# why function "gsub" act differently for small letter and capital letter while replacing when using "\"

Tags: r, regex

While replacing "\a" from a string using the function "gsub" gives me proper output as expected, but similar way replacing "\A" gives me error messages. Why is it happening?

```
> asd = "\asd"
> gsub("\\a","",asd)
[1] "sd"
> gsub("\\A","","\Asd")
Error: '\A' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\A"
>
```

I expect the output as "sd"

Comment: `gsub("\\A", "", "\\Asd")`?

Comment: returns `\\sd` not `sd`

Comment: it is single "\"

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-June/244039.html) link will clarify

Comment: This works.. `gsub("\\\\A","","\\Asd")`

Comment: *When in doubt, keep adding slashes until it works.-- Joran Elias (on how to escape a backslash in R)* - Rfortunes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\` is an escape character in R as well as in regex.

```
> cat("\A")
Error: '\A' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\A"

> cat("\\A")
\A
```

So you need to escape `\` in your string and then "double" escape it in your regex.

```
> gsub("\\\\A","","\\Asd")
[1] "sd"
```

`\a` is a special symbol, which is why it works replacing it. If you run `cat("\a")` in the command line it rings a bell, same as `alarm()`.

This however throws the same error:

```
> gsub("\\c","","\csd")
Error: '\c' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\c"
```

So it's not a matter of capital letters

Comment: though I think the question is why `gsub("\\a","","\asd")` works and `gsub("\\A","","\Asd")` doesn't ?

Comment: The link by sotos gives clarification on why `gsub("\\a","","\asd")` works. `\a` is a inbuilt escape sequence for the bell sound and thus doent need to be escaped kinda like `\n`. But this is not the case for `\A`